# node.js mocha test clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, mocha.js

I'm trying to test if a node.js Timers as be really cleared with Mocha and Should. By now, I don't find a good solution.
Trying with a simple example:

```
function myClass() {
    this.timers = Array();
}

myClass.sendEvent(fct, timeout) {
    this.timers.push(setTimeout(fct, timeout));
}

myClass.clearTimeout(timerId) {
    clearTimeout(this.timers[timerId]);
    this.timers[timerId] = null;
}
```

my mocha test simply check if my timer is really null. I obtain systematically an error saying that the timer (Node.js Timer object) is not null.

```
Uncaught AssertionError: expected Object {
  _called: false,
  _idleNext: Timer {
    '0': Function { name: 'listOnTimeout' },
    _idleNext: [Circular],
    _idlePrev: [Circular],
    msecs: 2000
  },
  _idlePrev: Timer {
    '0': Function { name: 'listOnTimeout' },
    _idleNext: [Circular],
    _idlePrev: [Circular],
    msecs: 2000
  },
  _idleStart: 18768,
  _idleTimeout: 2000,
  _onTimeout: Function { name: '' },
  _repeat: null
} to be null
```

Is there a good way to do that?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tests, here is what I found.
You can check Timer properties. It seems to work with a test checking if timer._idleTimeout == -1 and if timer._onTimeout == null

In my own case, I decided to assign null to the timer object so that the reference could be destroyed.
Then a simple test is:

```
should.not.exist(timer)
```